# How do I combine two strings and then convert it to an integer in C

Tags: c

I am reading a data file with numbers in it and extracting some of the numbers and converting them into one integer.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE* fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");

    int i;
    char data[5];

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
    {
        data[i] = fgetc(fp); 
    }  

    fclose(fp);
}
```

I have an array of dates in a char matrix and want to have separate arrays for the date month and year.  How do I take any n numbers from the data file and turn them into an n digit integer?  I have tried strcat followed by atoi but my lack of understanding of pointers gets in the way and I constantly get error messages?

I/O:

Input data (bank statement):

```
09,08,2014,"BOOK SHOP",12.34,5.67,
10,08,2014,"CAR MECHANIC",52.44,5.67,
11,08,2014,"CHIP SHOP",67.34,5.67,
```

The desired output is separate arrays for date, month, year, place of purchase, amount and balance.  I have separate arrays for each but the numbers are strings and not integers.  How can I convert each column to an integer array?

Comment: I did not understand question. Can you provide examples of input/output data?

Comment: Have you tried fscanf(fp, "%d", &data[i])?

Comment: there arent any blank lines if thats what you mean, there is a hidden character for new line in the input but its not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you `NULL` terminate your character array, then it is effectively a string representation of a number as far as C is concerned.  You can then just use `atoi()` directly on it:

```
int data_int;
char data_str[N+1];

for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    data_str[i] = fgetc(fp);

    /* to be really sure, you should make sure each character
     * you read is a decimal digit from '0' - '9'
     */

}

data_str[N] = '\0';
data_int = atoi(data_str);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are interested in reading the lines of data like:

```
09,08,2014,"BOOK SHOP",12.34,5.67,
10,08,2014,"CAR MECHANIC",52.44,5.67,
11,08,2014,"CHIP SHOP",67.34,5.67,
```

It looks like you can use `fscanf()`, but you need to be careful:

```
int day[20];
int month[20];
int year[20];
char name[20][15];
double amount[20];
double balance[20];

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    if (fscanf(fp, "%d ,%d ,%d , \" %14[^\"] \" ,%lf ,%lf ,",
              &day[i], &month[i], &year[i], name[i],
              &amount[i], &balance[i]) != 6)
        break;
}
```

You might not need every one of the spaces, and you'll never know whether the final comma on the line was missing.  Note that the code avoids buffer overflows, both by limiting the number of iterations on the loop and by limiting the length of the string field.  I chose `15` for the length of the names simply so that it is clear which number is the number of entries and which is the length of each entry.

You might prefer the `fgets()` and `sscanf()` approach:

```
int day[20];
int month[20];
int year[20];
char name[20][15];
double amount[20];
double balance[20];
char buffer[4096];
int i;    // Outside loop so it can be accessed after the loop

for (i = 0; i < 20 && fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != 0; i++)
{
    if (sscanf(buffer, "%d ,%d ,%d , \" %14[^\"] \" ,%lf ,%lf ,",
              &day[i], &month[i], &year[i], name[i],
              &amount[i], &balance[i]) != 6)
        break;
}
```

This will reject lines which don't match, whereas the original code using `fscanf()` directly would work with data like this:

```
09,08,2014,"BOOK SHOP",12.34,5.67,10,08,2014,"CAR MECHANIC",
52.44,5.67,11,
08,

2014,
"CHIP SHOP",


67.34,
5.67,
```

The code shown more or less replaces the lines in the question from `char data[5];` through the end of the loop.  You can add code to print the values read.

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    printf("%.4d-%.2d-%.2d  %-14s  %8.2f  %8.2f\n",
           year[j], month[j], day[j], name[j], amount[j], balance[j]);
```

Comment: #include <string.h>   
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(void)
    {

    FILE* fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");

    int i;
    int day[2];
    char data[2];  
    printf("%c",data[0]);
    scanf("%i",&day[0]);
    printf("%i",day[0]);


    return 0;
    }

Comment: @fluxrope: please explain your comment.  Yes, you would need to add the headers, the `int main(void)` and so on.  They're pretty routine, though.

Comment: I dont see any reference to the data array in your comment, how does it know where to get the data from

Comment: If I have to type the data in with scanf, then scanf is no use to me since the data is in a text file already.

Comment: Refresh the answer; it has used `fscanf()` for a number of minutes now.  In any case, on most systems, you could run `./your_program < data.txt` and your standard input would come from the data file.  There is no reference to the `data` array; the `data` array was of no use in reading the formatted data.  It wasn't big enough to hold most of the data fields as strings.  The name is not an integer; neither are the amount or balance fields.  If you like, you can rename `buffer` in the `fgets()`/`sscanf()` variant as `data`.